# Render dynamic html in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to render a dynamic html text provide by a API in react js but I don't know how to do.

for example :

```
   dynamicHtml= <div> hello <span color=red> StackOverFlow </span> </div>

   render() {

        return (
            <div>  {dynamicHtml} </div>
        );
   }
```

I want to dysplay only Hello StackOverFlow with the red color on StackOverFlow

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, what the question is, etc

Comment: I want to dysplay a dynamic html provided by a API.

Comment: ... repeating what you say in your question is not the same as expanding on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**

```
     function createMarkup(text) { return {__html: text}; };
     <render() {

            return (
               <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
            );
       }
```

Comment: Lol. I get the feeling that they advise against that... ;)

Comment: Lol. Wish they could have another solution.