# Trouble displaying {<p> blah blah <p>} in react as <p> tags are displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the nhs api to map and display its data within a react app..

```
        return (
            <div className="dashBody">

                {(this.props.nhsData).map((value, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="nhsInfoBox">
                            <a key={index} href={value.url} target="_blank">{value.name}</a>
                            <p>{value.description}</p>

                            {value.text}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
```

However **text** has been placed in the api object containing its own paragraph tags.

```
     {
        "@type": "WebPageElement",
        "name": "other_treatments",
        "description": "",
        "text": "<p> stuff </p>",
     },
```

So I figured that if I had just rendered {**value.text**} it would include the tags as normal and render as a paragraph element..

However it still contains its paragraph tags in the browser instead of displaying it **as** a paragraph.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337289/react-js-set-innerhtml-vs-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858660/render-dynamic-html-in-react-js). E.g., instead of `{value.text}`, `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value.text}} />`. (And yes, it's meant to be that ugly. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's all working now, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be dangerous and you should make sure that it is safe data.

You can use React prop called dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: value.text }} />
```

Comment: Surely there's a good dupetarget for this, rather than it needing another answer. *Edit: [There is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858660/render-dynamic-html-in-react-js), at least one.*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it looks like a typo to me

Comment: @Pointy - Typo?

Comment: The `<a>` tag is missing the closing `>` -- oh wait no, it's me, I'm blind

Comment: @Pointy - I'm not seeing that in the question (or rather, I am seeing it -- the `>`), and the OP has quoted the object they're outputting, which has `<p>` in a property's value... I've been known to be blind, though, so... :-) But it's just after `target="_blank"` isn't it? Ninja edit to the question?

Comment: @Pointy - Nine times out of ten, though, you're right and I've missed something. So... ;-)

Comment: Serves me right for trying to answer a React question :)